# What is Causing Spacing?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've just updated Twitter Bootstrap on a website I'm developing and it broke the layout in a number of places.

One of these places just has me stumped. The page in question can be seen at http://softcircuits.com/client/spacingtest.htm. (This is not the original site and will produce some scripting errors, but it shows the layout issue. The original site requires an account.)

There is a black 20px bar that runs across the very top of the page, with an image just below that. However, the image is placed about 22px from the top, leaving a 2px margin just below the black bar. After looking at this for a while, I still cannot figure out where this margin is coming from. I would like the image (and black areas on the side) to be flush up against the black bar.

I'm testing in Chrome. Would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) instead (and include it in the body of the question as well as linking to a live example).

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks for the comment. If I can figure out a way to create a short, self-contained, correct example that would illustrate a problem I'm having at some unknown location among the 1000s of lines of markup and code, I'll be very happy to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black bar itself (.status-outer) is 20px tall, but its containing element (.navbar-inner) is 22px tall.  Take off the gray border and trim it by one pixel to get it down to 20 and remove the gray line.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see the border. That takes me to 21px I think. I still don't see where that 1px is coming from.

Comment: The Metrics or Layout inspector shows the 1px bottom border, from `.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner, .navbar-static-top .navbar-inner {
border-width: 0 0 1px;
}`.  Looks like if you just remove that and the background color you'll get the layout you want.

Comment: Thanks for looking at that. I've spent quite a bit of time on this. The border you mentioned above was spot on, but there is still one pixel to account for. I couldn't figure out the background color comment. However, I did find `.navbar-inner:before, .navbar-inner:after { display: table; }`. If I disable that style, the gap goes away. Still trying to figure out why.